# Starting up a Windows Form Application hidden - High Memory Usage?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

Here is my situation. I am building a small Windows Form that will launch on Startup and run minimized in the System tray while not in use. The user will open the Form via a Notify Icon in the System tray and after submitting the form, the app will minimize back down to the System tray.

This all works fine. However, I noticed something a little odd. When the program is first launched, the Mem Usage in Task Manager shows ~14000 K. If I then open the Form from the system tray, it kicks up to ~16000 K. If I then minimize the form back down to the system tray, the usage drops to < 1000 K which is good. I have tried launching the application and waiting to see if the Usage dropped over time, but saw no change.

The reason I am concerned about this is because the application will be running in a Citrix Environment, so I would like to keep the Memory usage per instance down when the application is not in use, but I would prefer to not have to have the user open the application and minimize it every morning when they login.

If anyone has any suggestions or tips, I would greatly appreciate it. I will include the main blocks of code below.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);
    Rectangle r = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    this.Location = new Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height);
    currentWorkstation = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("clientname");
    if (currentWorkstation == null)
        currentWorkstation = Environment.MachineName;
    GC.KeepAlive(notifyIcon1);
    GC.KeepAlive(currentWorkstation);
}

private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
       Hide();
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fake "drop" in memory is because during a minimize event, Windows transfers the majority of application memory to virtual memory. During your startup, you're probably never actually closing a form/minimizing the application, therefore the cleanup never occurs.

More information can be seen here:

https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/why-does-task-manager-show-an-applications-memory-usage-drop-after-minimizing-it-to-the-the-taskbar/

My knowledge of this only comes from using this as a way to trick the J++ GC into running.  Telling a windows application to minimize/restore is nearly imperceptible to the user, but minimizes RAM accrual in a managed-memory VM.  I highly doubt this is "best practices" but it makes the numbers-guys in management happy.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I figured it had something to do with how Windows handles the minimize event. I added a `WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;` and `WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;` and now the Usage is at ~2000 K on startup. As you said, probably not "best practice" but makes the number guys happy. Thank you.

Comment: The technical term is "trimming the working set", it is not a cleanup.  It only happens on older versions of Windows, this is no longer done on Win7 and Win8.  RAM usage measurements are in general not useful, Windows unmaps pages whenever it needs to make room for other processes.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the clarification.  But just for my own education, isn't it true that frameworks can (and do/used to) hook into the "trim" event and force a GC event?

Comment: No, Windows doesn't generate any notification for this.  The GC only manages virtual memory.